# Add notAuthenticated() security rule for Firestore database collection

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to add a *match database* for a collection of documents without authentication. What is the correct way to do this?
This is the current security rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  function authenticated() { return request.auth.uid != null }
  
    match /users/{userId} {
       allow get: if authenticated() && request.auth.uid == userId;
       allow create: if authenticated() && request.auth.uid == userId;
       allow update, delete: if authenticated() && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    match /users/{userId}/products/{productId} {
      allow get: if authenticated() && request.auth.uid == userId;
            allow list: if authenticated() && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if authenticated() && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow update, delete: if authenticated() && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding this but I still get a Firestore *insufficient permissions error*:

```
    function notAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth == null;
    }
    
    match /share/{id}/documents {
 allow get:  if notAuthenticated();     
 allow create:  if notAuthenticated();
 allow read:  if notAuthenticated();
```

This is the JS code for adding a "share" to the Firestore.:

```
  const db = firebase.firestore()
  const docRef = db.collection('share').doc(val)

  docRef
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data().id)
      } else {
      
        console.log('No such document!')
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Error getting document:', error)
    })
enter code here
```

Comment: "I still get a Firestore insufficient permissions error:" Can you show the code that reproduces this error? And specifically in there: can you log `firebase.auth().currentUser` to show that it is `null`, as that is what your security rules require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code specifically only allows users that are not signed in to Firebase Authentication. So it rejects operations from users that *are* signed in.

It sounds like you want anyone to be able to read that specific collection, no matter whether they are signed in to Firebase Authentication or not.

The simplest rules for that would be:

```
match /share/{id}/documents {
  allow get: if true;
  allow create: if true;
  allow read: if true;
```

I'd definitely recommend adding some validation to the `create` rule in this case, as with the above anyone can write (which is what you want) whatever data they feel like (which you probably don't want) to your database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and recommendation. Would this be enough validation for the create rule? `if id.length >4 && id.length <20`  (only allow to write short strings)

Comment: There's no way for anyone but you to determine what is enough, but that rule will indeed check the length of the new document's ID.